# Ubuntu Windows Installer - Firewall

Tags: firewall

I installed Ubuntu with the Windows installer to use it along side. I could not find anything to activate a firewall so I thought its inbuilt and running. However now I read that I have to activate it manually? The command that was shown actually didn't prompt any response. Is it that the Windows installer version does not have that.

Also my greatest concern is that I was without firewall protection for 2-3 weeks and I am using alot of public networks (university and dorm(only cable but still)).

Comment: What firewall are you referring to?

Comment: Yes I was thinking of something like a firewall in windows that protects my labtop in a public network from others (who are in the same network) accesing my computer. I read the "Firewall"-setting you referred to and tried to run "sudo ufw enable" but that did not work. I am sorry if I dont really understand the firewall concept of Ubuntu. I am just afraid that someone who is connected to the same network (e.g. University) was able to acces my laptop. Is that possible in Ubuntu when I did not set up anything manually? I just installed the windows installer and then used it as I thought the "fi

Comment: Unless you have a strong password protected configuration , i don't think it is easy . Learn the firewall concept of Linux/ Ubuntu through the links in My below answer.

Comment: thank you very much for you prompt replies. So I did of course have a password. I will learn about the Firewall concept. Just one more clarification if you allow because it would be a great relieve to me right now as I do not have much time to read up to it right now: With a strong password somebody in the same public network (lan-network) cannot access my computer easily? even though I did not enable ufw.

Comment: See my answer and the links in the end, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Firewall software like in windows,

The **Linux kernel in Ubuntu** provides a packet filtering system called **netfilter**, and the traditional interface for manipulating netfilter are the [**iptables**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) suite of commands.

**iptables** provide a complete **firewall** solution that is both highly configurable and highly flexible.

You can install  [Uncomplicated FireWall](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gufw/), a frontend to [Iptables](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/iptables.8.html) .

You can further refer to Official [Firewall setting up page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html)

**Note: Further discussion and references**

[Creating a Firewall for Your Ubuntu Desktop](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876124)

[Basic iptables how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

[Ubuntu Basic Security](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity)

[Do i need firewall in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871177).

[do I need a firewall, anti-virus, anti-spyware tools?](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/security#firewallantivirus)