# How to stop firewall

Tags: firewall, maven-3

I am new to Ubuntu. I am developer and working with `maven3`. I am unable to download dependencies from [this site](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/maven-jetty-plugin-6.1.20.pom).

When I tried in Windows it was a `404` exception but when I stopped my anti-virus it was working fine. I tried the same in Ubuntu but still no luck.

I have tried running `sudo ufw disable` but still no luck.

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo ufw status`?

Comment: And have you made any changes to your firewall settings?

Comment: If you think it is the firewall, try this command: `sudo iptables -L` It will list all rules you have.

Comment: I do not think Ubuntu firewall would block you from downloading files from some website. Unless you previously changed its configuration to do that.

Comment: I dont know what to do...please let me know if you need further details ..which can solve my issue...Thanks in advance...

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the firewall...I think there have been some updates installed ..with that there might be change in the settings..but I am not sure..But when i am trying to open thie below link in windows it was opened after disabling the anti virus..repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/… ..So i think the same thing applies here..The status of ufw is inactive...krishna@krishna-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo ufw status [sudo] password for krishna: Status: inactive

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is related to the firewall then you can verify it by temporarily turning off the firewall by using `sudo iptables -F` . Alternatively you can also try `sudo service ufw stop`.

Furthermore, `sudo ufw status` should give the status of the firewall and `sudo iptables -L` should list all the rules. [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) is front end for `iptables`.

**More information**

- [IptablesHowTo - Disabling the firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Disabling_the_firewall)
- [How to start/stop iptables in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161551/how-to-start-stop-iptables-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with **ufw**

for help about it just do

```
ufw --help
```

and you can see that to disable it you can do:

```
ufw disable
```

Comment: Still the same i am unable to open this url..http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/maven-jetty-plugin-6.1.20.pom

Comment: If you have stoped firewall then your question has been answered. May be firewall is not the problem .

Comment: Shahverdy, Then what is blocking me to open the below link? any suggestion? http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/maven-jetty-plugin-6.1.20.pom

Comment: What sites are you able to see?

Comment: I could see http://search.maven.org but not able to see http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/

Comment: try to `sudo iptables -L` and give us the output ...

Comment: krishna@krishna-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for krishna: 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
krishna@krishna-System-Product-Name:~$

Comment: Your problem is not firewall. there is no rules that ban you from accessing that page.